# What's the difference between "friend struct A;" and "friend A;" syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

What is the difference between doing:

```
struct A;
struct B { friend struct A; };
```

and

```
struct A;
struct B { friend A; };
```

What does it mean to leave out `struct` in the second part?

Comment: Nothing whatsoever, given the snippets you've provided.

Comment: As for the second code snippet, I wanted to say `#define A void foobar(int,double)` but the preceding forward declaration of `struct A;` invalidates that (half-)joke. Eh.

Comment: In case you don't agree with the title change I proposed, feel free to reedit. I just thought that the original title sounded more like .. teen peer-support forum :| Maybe that's just me today..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl `#define A A; void foobar(int,double)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference is that if you write `friend A;`, `A` must be a known type name, that is it must be declared before.

If you write `friend struct A;`, this itself is a declaration of `A`, so no prior declaration is needed:

```
struct B { friend struct A; }; // OK
```

---

There are several subtleties though. For example, `friend class/struct A` declares class `A` in innermost enclosing namespace of class `B` (thanks to [Captain Obvlious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845568/captain-obvlious)):

```
class A;
namespace N {
    class B {
        friend A;         // ::A is a friend
        friend class A;   // Declares class N::A despite prior declaration of ::A,
                          // so ::A is not a friend if previous line is commented
    };
}
```

Also there are several other cases when you can write only `friend A`:

1. `A` is a typedef-name:

   ```
   class A;
   typedef A A_Alias;

   struct B {
       // friend class A_Alias;  - ill-formed
       friend A_Alias;
   };
   ```
2. `A` is a template parameter:

   ```
   template<typename A>
   struct B { 
       // friend class A;  - ill-formed
       friend A;
   };
   ```

Comment: IIRC, in the latter you can use full `friend typename A`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl no, [you can't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f080bdde9d602ac1), you are probably confusing it with [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/818df2034d15bcf6)

Comment: @AntonSavin: yes, that's what I was referring to. I forgot that's only for ('namespace-')qualified names.